# How do I parse an unknown number of inputs with PHP?

Tags: php, forms, input

Lets say I have something like this:
http://gyazo.com/642987562175afc6d11a962762327744.png?1329570534

Basically, the user fills out this form, and if there are more people, pressing tab on the last form will add another input. I believe Quizlet does something similar.

How would I parse all these inputs with PHP? I obviously don't know how many inputs there will be.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create every (similar) element of the form (in html) as an entry of an array (in php). See http://php.net/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays
You can just iterate over the elements then

```
foreach ($_POST['MyArray'] as $element) { echo $element; }
```

Just to make it complete: If you click on the link above then you see, how your form elements should look like.

```
<input name="MyArray[]" />
<input name="MyArray[]" />
<input name="MyArray[]" />
<input name="MyArray[]" />
```

Comment: It's worth noting that when you write the HTML for the inputs you'll specify `<input name="xy[]"` as the name of all the inputs to have the array created in that name and placed in the GET or POST php global array.

Comment: @itsmequinn Thats mentioned on php.net (see link). Ive added it to the answer for the case, that php.net is eventually not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each input has a unique name by incrementing it for each additional field, eg:

```
<input type="text" name="field-1" />
<input type="text" name="field-2" />
<input type="text" name="field-3" />
```

Then when you submit it to your php script you have access to all form fields in the $_GET or $_POST arrays, depending on your form submission method.

You can do a simple while loop to iterate over $_GET['field-1'], $_GET['field-2'], $_GET['field-n'].

Make sense?

Answer (score -1):

Variable-length argument lists

PHP has support for variable-length argument lists in user-defined functions. This is really quite easy, using the func_num_args(), func_get_arg(), and func_get_args() functions.

No special syntax is required, and argument lists may still be explicitly provided with function definitions and will behave as normal.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php :)